# Set identity policy for all areas except one

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to implement role-based authorization in my Razor Pages application.

Here's what I have so far.

```
// Create authorization policies
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Staff", p => p.RequireRole(Role.Staff));
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", p => p.RequireRole(Role.Admin));
});

// Set authorization
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{

    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/", Role.Staff);
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("/", "/", Role.Staff);

    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Admin", "/", Role.Admin);
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Leasing", "/", Role.Staff);
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Repair", "/", Role.Staff);
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Storage", "/", Role.Staff);
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Transloading", "/", Role.Staff);

    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Error");
});
```

This seems to work. The problem is having to explicitly specify each of my area folders. What happens if a new area is added but they forget to add it here? That's not a secure approach.

*Note: I'm not sure what `options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("/", "/", Role.Staff)` does, but it's pretty clear it doesn't set authorization for all areas like I want.*

How can I set the policy for *every area* (including areas added in the future) to "Staff", except for the *Admin* area, which should have the "Admin" policy?

*Note: I'm using the latest version of .NET 5.*

Comment: I totally understand your question, but the policies cannot be applied at the Razor Page handler level, they must be applied to the Page. Policies can be applied to Razor Pages by using an [authorization convention](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0). And we can only use the AuthorizeAreaFolder() method to set authorize for each area. I didn't find an easier method to set the authorize for all areas at once. I suggest you could submit a feedback to [dotnet/aspnetcore](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues).

Answer (score -1):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Comment: What about it ?